# Avoid multiple events on a dropdown: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, setstate, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to handle a tree inside of a checkbox. I am using onClick, onClose and onOpen for achieving opening of dropdown. But somehow onclick and onclose when clicked on semantic-ui-react. Can someone help me how to achieve this?

On click of dropdown it should open the dropdown and then toggle it, whenever tree changes are made it should be open.

https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-yzemk?file=/index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Dropdown } from "semantic-ui-react";
import CheckboxTree from "react-checkbox-tree";
import "react-checkbox-tree/lib/react-checkbox-tree.css";
const nodes = [
  {
    value: "mars",
    label: "Mars",
    children: [
      { value: "phobos", label: "Phobos" },
      { value: "deimos", label: "Deimos" }
    ]
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checked: [],
    expanded: [],
    options: [],
    open: false
  };

  onClose = e => {
    console.log("on close");
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  onOpen = e => {
    console.log("on open");
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  onChange = e => {
    console.log("on change");
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  onClick = e => {
    console.log("on click");
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dropdown
          className="icon"
          selection
          options={this.state.options}
          text="Select"
          open={this.state.open}
          onClose={this.onClose}
          onOpen={this.onOpen}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          onClick={this.onClick}
        >
          <Dropdown.Menu>
            <Dropdown.Item>
              <CheckboxTree
                nodes={nodes}
                checked={this.state.checked}
                expanded={this.state.expanded}
                onCheck={checked =>
                  this.setState({ checked }, () => {
                    console.log(this.state.checked);
                  })
                }
                onExpand={expanded => this.setState({ expanded })}
              />
            </Dropdown.Item>
          </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: So what is your desired behavior? Because, the code in the sandbox works just fine

Comment: click should toggle the dropdown toggling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you're having issue with dropdown not closing, I see in your code you're setting `open` to true in `onClose`.

```js
onClose = e => {
    console.log("on close");
    this.setState({ open: false }); // this is `true` in your code
  };
```

As a further suggestion, use [callback function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) in `setState` when you're using the existing state to modify the state.

```
// this.setState({ open: !this.state.open }); don't use this
this.setState((prevState)=>{
  return {
    open: !prevState.open,
  };
});
```

Comment: but on selecting something inside checkbox, it gets closed. I want it to be kept open. Only  on click of dropdown it should open/close

Comment: I don't know the internal implementation of your Dropdown compoment but it seems when you click `>` the blur event is called which closes the dropdown. This doesn't happen when you click checkbox. So may be you can check that code and add appropriate e.stopPropagation() to not close the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Your OnClick method changes state.open everytime element is clicked - even when u click inner element.
That's why your dropdown is closed.

--

I think this is what you want, although I don't think this is the most elegant solution:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Dropdown } from "semantic-ui-react";
import CheckboxTree from "react-checkbox-tree";
import "react-checkbox-tree/lib/react-checkbox-tree.css";
const nodes = [
  {
    value: "mars",
    label: "Mars",
    children: [
      { value: "phobos", label: "Phobos" },
      { value: "deimos", label: "Deimos" }
    ]
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checked: [],
    expanded: [],
    options: [],
    open: false
  };
/*
  onClose = e => {
    console.log(e.target)
    ///if(e.target.role==="listbox"){
      console.log("on close");
      this.setState({ open: false }); // this is `true` in your code  
    //}
};
  onOpen = e => {
    console.log("on open");
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };
  
  onChange = e => {
    console.log("on change");
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };*/
  onClick = e => {
    if(e.target.id==="dropdown" || e.target.className==="text" || e.target.className==="dropdown icon"){
      this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
    }
    console.log("on click");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dropdown
          id="dropdown"
          className="icon"
          selection
          options={this.state.options}
          text="Select"
          open={this.state.open}
          onClose={this.onClose}
          onOpen={this.onOpen}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          onClick={this.onClick}
        >
          <Dropdown.Menu>
            <Dropdown.Item>
              <CheckboxTree
                nodes={nodes}
                checked={this.state.checked}
                expanded={this.state.expanded}
                onCheck={checked =>
                  this.setState({ checked }, () => {
                    console.log(this.state.checked);
                  })
                }
                onExpand={expanded => this.setState({ expanded })}
              />
            </Dropdown.Item>
          </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>

        {/* <CheckboxTree
          nodes={nodes}
          checked={this.state.checked}
          expanded={this.state.expanded}
          onCheck={checked => this.setState({ checked })}
          onExpand={expanded => this.setState({ expanded })}
        /> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I did try commenting out the code inside `onClick` method and that doesn't seem to fix the issue